# Spring cloud stream rabbitMQ consumer with topic wildcards

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to use spring cloud stream rabbitmq and send messages to the same exchange but with different topics. And there will be consumers who will consume messages of one or more topics using the wildcard in the bindings. Is there an example for this scenario?

I'm guessing I can use the topics as partitionKey. In this way all messages will go to the same exchange. But I'm not clear on how to setup the consumer

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple destination names for the Spring Cloud Stream consumer as the property `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.destination` accepts comma separated list of destination names.

Comment: But you can't use the partitionKey to "name" the queue - partitions are numeric and calculated from the key.

Comment: Can I put all topics in an enum and use the enum as partitionKey? And in the consumer side, I'll use the same enum and mention the topics that I'm interested in listening. Will this work?